# Opening a function that does something through command arguments

Tags: c++, function, command-line-arguments, argv, argc

Suppose I wanted to open up the program through command (using argc and argv). You get to your program name, open the program. It gives you the .exe. Then once your program.exe is run, add another argument to it such as (program.exe open), which should open something in your program.

```
if (argc >= 5){
    if (int(argv[1]) == 1){
        function1();
        function2();
        function3();

    }

}
```

Basically in this case, if the user were to input program.exe 1, (1 being the opening in this case) it should do the following functions. Why is this incorrect logically? (as there is nothing displaying)

Comment: For a start, `program.exe 1` will not result in `argc >= 5`...

Answer (score 2):

What you need is this :

```
if (argc >= 2){ // the argc is count of supplied argument
                // including executable name
    if ( (argv[1][0]-'0') == 1){
        //argv[1] will be "1"
        //so take first character using argv[1][0]--> gives '1'-->49
        //substract ASCII value of 0 i.e. 48
       //Note: - This will only work for 0-9 as supplied argument
        function1();
        function2();
        function3();

    }

}
```

Comment: Indeed, but not very extensible (in the sense that this will break for input values > 9)...

Answer (score 1):

Your conversion of argv[1] to int does not work. You could use [atoi()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi):

```
if (argc >= 2){
    if (atoi(argv[1]) == 1){
        function1();
        function2();
        function3();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for outputting any cout << . However, when trying to use the functions, it displays nothing. I have one function that opens a file, another that opens another file, and then at the end of those functions i have a cout of that text. No text is present when calling the function in the if argv statement

Comment: I edited my answer to compare argc against 2. If you are calling your program like this: `program.exe 1`, then argc is going to be 2.

Answer (score 0):

Because `int(argv[1])` doesn't convert the *string* `"1"` to the `int` `1`.  Try this instead:

```
if (argv[1][0] == '1') {
```

Comment: Of course if argv[1] happens to be "10" this may not do what's required